# Keyboard not showing above Custom AlertDialog when user clicks on EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, android-alertdialog

I'd like to show keyboard to the user when I my alertdialog ABOVE it, I've already tried with

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

however, keyboard gets displayed UNDER the dialog.
I've already set my activity in manifest like this:

```
  <activity
     android:name=".ActivityMain"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
   />
```

Here's the code I used to generate the dialog

```
  public void createConstDialog(String[] textstring) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_editconstantformula, null);
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            builder.setTitle("Edit Values");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
        // ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_view_calculator_formula, R.id.constid, textstring);
            lv = (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.list_view1);
            final MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long viewId) {
                    mConstid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.constid);
                    mConstid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Log.d("touched", "" + position);
                        }
                    });
                    mConstvalue = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.constvaluez);
                    mConstvalue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Log.d("touched", "" + position);
                        }
                    });


                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
                        View wantedView = lv.getChildAt(i);
                        mConstvalue = (EditText) wantedView.findViewById(R.id.constvaluez);
                        String letter = lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                        String value = mConstvalue.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("touched", (letter + "valore: " + mConstvalue.getText().toString()));
                        mFormulaEditText.setText(mFormulaEditText.getText().toString().replaceAll(letter, value));
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }




    R.layout.dialog_editconstantformula

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But with a similar code in a different activity, (from AlertDialog.builder to (false);), I get Keyboard showing on click on an edittext. I also tried to remove my listview from the edittext, however nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you should replace `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` with `"android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`